# How Can I Change or Adjust Header Size in CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to adjust the Header size for a project. I had tried changing it with 
 .body but it landed in failure. Is there anyway I can adjust the size?

```
CSS
#header{
   height:700px;
   width:1600px;
   border-color: #00FF00;
}


HTML
   <header>
     <h1> <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="img/focus.png"/><span>Focus</span></h1>
     <p>A landing page for your app with focus</p>
   </header>
```

Comment: You're going to have to add some code, friend-- there is simply not enough information in this question for anyone to give you a meaningful answer: [ask]  I'd recommend doing it quickly before the downvote train really gets rolling...

Comment: what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

[Read about CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), start with the basic difference between `type`, `id` and `class` selectors.

You have an id selector when you want type:

```
header{
   height:700px;
   width:1600px;
   border-color: #00FF00;
}
```

Comment: It's working, but now I have white space on the top of the image. I adjust that white space with the margins right?

Comment: Margin or padding, use the browser developer tools to inspect the element and find out where the whitespace is coming from.